Unity. Inspector references to objects disappear after restarting the scene
The bug occurs in two cases:

When I restart the scene
When I go to another scene and then come back

The game works correctly only after the first start of the scene.
The essence of the bug is that there is an error:

MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

Although looking at the inspector, you can see that there is a link to the object and clicking on it in the hierarchy opens this object. To get around this problem I used GameObject.Find and it worked, but there are a lot of such links and I need to fix it another way.
The code where the error concerns the ropeParent object:
if (ropeParent.childCount > 0)
{
    Destroy(ropeParent.GetChild(0).gameObject);
}

ropeParent field:
[SerializeField] private Transform ropeParent;

Inspector screenshots:


I came to the conclusion that the link works in the inspector but for some reason is not available in the game

I need to know more about your class and how you set it up, particularly regarding the ([SerializeField] private Transform ropeParent) field.
Typically, the following situations can lead to issues or errors:

Modifying a property in Play Mode: All changes made to MonoBehaviours during Play Mode will revert after pausing the game.
ScriptableObject fields: If a field of a ScriptableObject references a scene object, it will reset if you change the scene or perform other similar actions due to object lifetimes.
When modifying an object via script (editor functions), you have to call SetDirty() and save the object to ensure the changes persist.

Please provide more information about your class and how you are managing the object references, so we can identify the root cause of the issue and find an appropriate solution.

this bug exists in half of all fields. Its not one class issue. Still trying to fix it, but thanks for tips
